# Chrome Devtools, HTMLDivElement style property set BEFORE function called

Tags: javascript, css, dom, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I have a script with the function `addBorder()` which sets the first div's a border style property to `"2px solid red"`. But when I `console.log()` the `div`, the *border is already added before the function call* for `addBorder()`.

```js
let div = document.querySelector("div");

function log(){
    console.log("before addBorder() called: ", div);  
}

function addBorder(){
    console.log("addBorder() called");
    console.log("before css property set:   ", div);   
    div.style.border = "2px solid red";
    console.log("after:                     ", div);
}

log();
addBorder();
```

```html
<div>one</div>
```

---

**Here's what the console shows in Chrome Devtools:**
[image]
As you can see, **the *border is already added before the function call* for `addBorder()`** and before the `.style` property is set. What I would expect is for the first two logs to be `<div>one</div>`, and the last to be `<div style="border: 2px solid red;">one</div>`, since that is the only log called after the property is set.

Maybe this is a bug in Chrome devtools, because it actually works as expected in the stackoverflow console for the code snippet on this post.

Another strange behavior- if I slowly **step through the code in the debugger the logs look *completely different*:**
[image]

But the result here isn't what I'd expect either, since the last log shows the original state of with the div, `<div>one</div>` without the border style applied- `style="border: 2px solid red;"`.

Is this strange behavior due to some flaw in my code? **Or** is it a Chrome devtools bug?

Comment: Devtools console contains a pointer to the actual element in all three messages which is why it displays identically. You might want to log out just the property itself.

Comment: It's not a bug; it's how the console works. Output is live, and updated when the object changes.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you! I have yet to learn about pointers, maybe if I look into those I'll understand this better. Thanks for the suggestion, logging div.style.border instead of div yielded the result I would expect. Thank you.